# Avoiding inner group in regex return

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm working on an html extraction, and I'm using regular expressions in minor duties. I'm using python `re` module, and I'd like to avoid inner groups to be returned when defining the group is necessary -- or, at least, when it seems to be needed.

As an example, consider the string:

```
line = u" 07.49 (43 votes) "
```

And the expression:

```
expr = lambda x: re.findall("(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)\D*(\d+)", x)
```

The return of the application is:

```
expr(line)
[(u'7.49', u'.49', u'43')]
```

And I'd like to have the following as result:

```
expr(line)
[(u'7.49', u'43')]
```

But I need to define the inner group `(\.\d{1,2})?` in `"(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)\D*(\d+)"`, as the decimal part of the number may not appear.

Is there a way to avoid this *extra group*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Use the non-capturing group instead.

```
(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)\D*(\d+)
```

Comment: is this a python specific syntax, or is it valid on sed, egrep, and other tools?

Comment: @Rubens.. This is Regex specific, and will be valid for all the Regex tools.

Comment: Whoa! Brilliant! Been looking for this for a long time D: Thank you guys! Just an extra question: can I `negate` a group, like using `[^...]`, but having `...` to be a group?

Comment: You should use a negative lookahead for that.

Comment: Thank you all! I'm much happier with regex now (: